# Confusing C++ code involving *this?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, this

Could someone explain this code?  I don't understand line 3:

```
MyString MyString::operator+(const MyString &str)
{
    MyString ss(*this); //----> explain this part
    ss += str;
    return ss;
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This code:

```
MyString ss(*this);
```

Says "declare a new variable of type `MyString` that's named `ss`, and initialize it as a copy of `*this`."  Inside of a member function, `this` is a pointer to the receiver object (the object that the member function is acting on), so `*this` is a reference to the receiver object.  Consequently, you can read this as "make a new `MyString` that's called `ss` and is a copy of the receiver object."

The idiom being used here is implementing `operator +` in terms of `operator +=`.  The idea is to make a copy of the receiver object, use `operator +=` to add the parameter to the copy, and then to return the copy.  It's a widely-used trick that simplifies the implementation of freestanding operators given implementation of the corresponding compound assignment operator.

Hope this helps!

Comment: The `operator+` in question isn't freestanding, it's the member operator -- otherwise there'd be no `this` :-)

Comment: Sorry, by "freestanding" I mean "not the compound assignment version."  That probably wasn't the best terminology. :-)

Comment: @templatetypedef: "Non-mutating" :)

Answer (score 3):

This is an instance of the common code reuse technique to implement one operator in terms of another.

Suppose we have already defined a compound-plus operator:

```
class X
{
  X & operator+=(const X&);
};
```

This unary operator allows us to write `a += b`, it modifies `a` and returns a reference to itself. This is all fine and good. Now if we also want to provide a copying, binary plus opearator `a + b`, which returns a the new value by value and leaves both `a` and `b` unchanged, then we want to take advantage of the code we've already written for the compound operator. We do so by calling the unary operator on a *temporary copy* of `a`:

```
X X::operator+(const X & b) const { return X(*this) += b; }
                                           ^^^^^^^^
                                           temporary copy
```

This is exactly what your code does, only a bit more verbosely. You could as well have written `return MyString(*this) += str;`

There are other idioms with follow a similar spirit, such as implementing non-const access in terms of const access, copy-assign in terms of copy-construct and swap, and move-assign in terms of move-construct and swap. It always boils down to avoiding code duplication.

Answer (score 1):

It's a constructor for `MyString` that takes the value of the current object (of type `MyString`) as its argument.

Answer (score 1):

From what I can tell that is a copy constructor which creates a new MyString with the contents of the current MyString object.

Answer (score 1):

`ss` is a new string which gets constructed with a *copy constructor* from the original string.